# Spring Task Scheduler - No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ubuntu, cron

**Error:** *No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] is defined*

Here is my console log:

```
10:32:35.742 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'cronTrigger' to allow for resolving potential circular references
10:32:35.746 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - No @Scheduled annotations found on bean class: class org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger
10:32:35.747 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'cronTrigger'
10:32:35.747 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'taskExecutor'
10:32:35.747 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'taskExecutor'
10:32:35.747 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'webConfig'
10:32:35.749 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'taskExecutor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
10:32:35.757 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - No @Scheduled annotations found on bean class: class java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
10:32:35.757 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'taskExecutor'
10:32:35.757 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'getInternalResourceViewResolver'
10:32:35.757 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'getInternalResourceViewResolver'
10:32:35.757 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'webConfig'
10:32:35.770 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'getInternalResourceViewResolver' to allow for resolving potential circular references
10:32:35.781 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - No @Scheduled annotations found on bean class: class org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver
10:32:35.781 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'getInternalResourceViewResolver'
10:32:35.785 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@31b09c11]
10:32:35.785 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
10:32:35.788 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
10:32:35.788 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
10:32:35.788 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mvcResourceUrlProvider'
10:32:35.788 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider - Looking for resource handler mappings
10:32:35.789 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider - No resource handling mappings found
10:32:35.789 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'webConfig'
10:32:35.794 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'cronTrigger'
10:32:35.808 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Could not find default TaskScheduler bean

//Exception Starts from here.
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.finishRegistration(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:183) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:162) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:85) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4726) [catalina.jar:8.0.20.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162) [catalina.jar:8.0.20.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.20.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.20.B]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.20.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.20.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581) [catalina.jar:8.0.20.B]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683) [catalina.jar:8.0.20.B]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
10:32:35.809 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'taskExecutor'
10:32:35.827 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletConfigInitParams]
10:32:35.827 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletContextInitParams]
10:32:35.827 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [jndiProperties]
10:32:35.827 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
10:32:35.830 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] not found - trying original name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].
10:32:35.830 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
```

Here is **WebConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.project")
public class WebConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer 
{    
protected static final Logger slf4jLogger  = Logger.getLogger(WebConfig.class.getName());
private static final String cronExpression = "0 0 * * * ?";



/*@Bean
public MobileNotifSchedulerBean schedulerbean()
{
    return new MobileNotifSchedulerBean();
}*/

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver()
{
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setSuffix(".htm");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
CronTrigger cronTrigger() 
{
    //String timeZone = "Asia/Calcutta";

    String timeZone = null;
    HashSet<String> userTimeZonesfromDB = FetchUserTimeZones.fetchUserTimeZone();
    for (String s : userTimeZonesfromDB) 
    {
        timeZone = s;
        slf4jLogger.info(s);
    }
    return new CronTrigger(cronExpression, TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
}


@Override
public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) 
{

    taskRegistrar.addCronTask(new CronTask(new MobileNotifSchedulerBean(), cronTrigger()));
}

@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
public Executor taskExecutor() 
{
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
}   
}
```

Here is my **MobileNotifSchedulerBean:**

```
@EnableScheduling
public class MobileNotifSchedulerBean implements Runnable 
{
protected static final Logger slf4jLogger  = Logger.getLogger(MobileNotifSchedulerBean.class.getName());


public void sendQuestionNotif() 
{
    try 
    {
        HashSet<String> reg_ids = FetchRegistrationIDs.fetchItems();
        for (String s : reg_ids) 
        {
            String REGISTRATION_IDs = s;
            slf4jLogger.info(s);                
            MobileSNSPushNotification.sendNotification(REGISTRATION_IDs);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        slf4jLogger.error(e);
        slf4jLogger.error(e.getMessage());
        slf4jLogger.error(e.getStackTrace());
    }
}


@Override
public void run() 
{
    sendQuestionNotif();
}
}
```

I am using Java 8 and Spring MVC 4. I want to solve this error 
*"No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] is defined"*
kindly help me. TIA.

Comment: The correct answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31820129/587641

Answer (score 4):

This exception is logged from **org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.inishRegistration()**:

```
if (this.registrar.hasTasks() && this.registrar.getScheduler() == null) {
    Assert.state(this.beanFactory != null, "BeanFactory must be set to find scheduler by type");
    try {
        // Search for TaskScheduler bean...
        this.registrar.setTaskScheduler(this.beanFactory.getBean(TaskScheduler.class));
    }
    catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
        logger.debug("Could not find default TaskScheduler bean", ex);
        // Search for ScheduledExecutorService bean next...
        try {
            this.registrar.setScheduler(this.beanFactory.getBean(ScheduledExecutorService.class));
        }
        catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex2) {
            logger.debug("Could not find default ScheduledExecutorService bean", ex);
            // Giving up -> falling back to default scheduler within the registrar...
        }
    }
}
```

This process attempts to set the task scheduler for the registrar. For this, it tries to find a registered scheduler bean through **BeanFactory.getBean** method:

1. Tries to find a configured **TaskScheduler bean**, if not found then fallbacks
   to->
2. finding **ScheduledExecutorService bean**, if not found then fallbacks to->
3. using the **default scheduler** within the registrar
   (The same is indicated in the code comment above: **// Giving up -> falling back to default scheduler within the registrar...**)

If any of the TaskScheduler or ScheduledExecutorService bean is not found in the container, BeanFactory.getBean throws an exception.

ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor in turn logs these exception with DEBUG level:

```
logger.debug("Could not find default TaskScheduler bean", ex);
logger.debug("Could not find default ScheduledExecutorService bean", ex);
```

So, in conclusion these exceptions are just logged in process of finding a fallback option for task scheduler bean, and they do not affect the execution of the application.

The log level of this class can be elevated so that these DEBUG level messages are not logged like so:

```
<!-- Elevate the log level for 'org.springframework.scheduling' since in
     process of registering the scheduled task, Spring's
     ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor tries to find TaskScheduler and
     ScheduledExecutorService beans and then fallbacks to its internal
     scheduler but in the process logs exceptions when it cannot find those
     beans registered.
-->
<logger name="org.springframework.scheduling">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>
```

Comment: I agree it's a harmless message, but in my case I solved it by changing my `@Bean` declaration to return `TaskExecutor` rather than the base class `Executor`

Answer (score -1):

Annote your `MobileNotifSchedulerBean` with `@Configurable`. I think it will work.