# Spring Async issue when upgrading from 4.2.0.RC3 to 4.2.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, executorservice, spring-websocket

I've a web application using the spring(4.2.x) artifacts spring-webmvc, spring-messaging, spring-websocket

I've the below @Enable* annotations in my spring config java class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableAsync
@EnableMBeanExport
```

WebSocket is used for broadcasting messages to browser clients.
And there are few async methods annotated with @Async

The application was working fine with spring version 4.2.0.RC3. But when I changed it to the GA release 4.2.0.RELEASE, I get the below exception on startup. If I remove @EnableAsync it works fine, but I need the async functionality.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 4: clientOutboundChannelExecutor,messageBrokerTaskScheduler,clientInboundChannelExecutor,brokerChannelExecutor
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:366)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
    org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:128)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:682)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:539)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of your `@Configuration` must implement `AsyncConfigurer` to specify the particular `TaskExecutor` for `@Async` methods.

Otherwise it is in confuse which one to choose from the `applicationContext`.

Even if it worked with `RC3` it doesn't matter that it is correct, hence the bug has been fixed for `GA`.

**UPDATE**

The source code in the `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` looks like:

```
Executor executorToUse = this.executor;
if (executorToUse == null) {
    try {
        // Search for TaskExecutor bean... not plain Executor since that would
        // match with ScheduledExecutorService as well, which is unusable for
        // our purposes here. TaskExecutor is more clearly designed for it.
        executorToUse = beanFactory.getBean(TaskExecutor.class);
    }
    catch (NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException ex) {
        try {
            executorToUse = beanFactory.getBean(DEFAULT_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME, TaskExecutor.class);
        }
        catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex2) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("More than one TaskExecutor bean exists within the context, " +
                    "and none is named 'taskExecutor'. Mark one of them as primary or name it " +
                    "'taskExecutor' (possibly as an alias); or specify the AsyncConfigurer interface " +
                    "and implement getAsyncExecutor() accordingly.", ex);
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
        logger.debug("Could not find default TaskExecutor bean", ex);
        // Giving up -> falling back to default executor within the advisor...
    }
}
```

So, I guess before in between moving from RC3 to GA you have had a `taskExecutor` bean on the matter.

As we see by you StackTrace there is such a bean already...

Comment: Which one was the default in RC3, and what's the difference between them?

Comment: @Artem There is no mention to specify a particular `TaskExecutor` for `@Async` methods in the Reference Documentation. I think spring should provide a default `TaskExecutor` if none is specified.

Comment: See an `UPDATE` in my answer.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks, I extended `AsyncConfigurerSupport` in one of the `@Configuration` class.

Answer (score 27):

Add the bean at Spring application context configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppContext extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }
}
```

I suggest that you refer to [linuxism.tistory.com/2076](http://linuxism.tistory.com/2076)

If you declare your executors in XML, then you can create a class and name it TaskExecutor. Then when Spring tries to find the TaskExecutor bean, it will find this one.

```
@Component
public class TaskExecutor extends SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those like myself who are still using old-fashioned XML configuration....

This was working for me before Spring 4.2:

```
<task:annotation-driven />
<task:executor id="executorA" pool-size="50" />
<task:executor id="executorB" pool-size="100" />

@Async("executorA")
public void executeA() {}

@Async("executorB")
public void executeB() {}
```

As pointed out by Artem, Spring 4.2 is getting confused about which pool to use for qualifier-less async methods even when you don't have such methods in your application.

To fix it, I used this:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="defaultExecutor"/>

<task:executor id="defaultExecutor" pool-size="1" queue-capacity="0"/>
<task:executor id="executorA" pool-size="50" />
<task:executor id="executorB" pool-size="100" />

@Async("executorA")
public void executeA() {}

@Async("executorB")
public void executeB() {}
```

Note that if you add qualifier-less @Async methods, then those methods will use the defaultExectuor thread-pool:

```
@Async
public void myDefaultExecute() {}
```

And, of course, executeA() calls will use executorA thread-pool and executeB() calls will use executorB thread-pool.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a customized bean name and inject the bean by that name resolved my issue.

Configuration Bean creation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncConfiguration.class);

    @Bean(name = "asyncTaskExecutor")
    public Executor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        LOGGER.debug("Creating Async Task Executor");
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Executor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

}
```

Bean Injection.

```
 @Async("asyncTaskExecutor")
 public Future<ATIQueryResult> processApiMessage(String msisdn) {
 
 }
```